# Matrix Factorization of lower triangular and unit upper triangular.

Tags: matrices, matlab, factoring

So I have a matrix.

$$A =\begin{bmatrix}
8  &&  -3   &&  2  &&  -1\\
-3   &&  8   &&  0   &&  2\\
2   &&  0  &&   8  &&  -3\\
-1   &&  2  &&  -3  &&  8
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And the $[L,U] = Doolittle(A)$ is

$$L =
\begin{bmatrix}
1.0000    &&    0      &&   0      &&  0\\
       -0.3750  &&  1.0000     &&    0    &&     0\\
        0.2500  &&  0.1091   && 1.0000    &&     0\\
       -0.1250   && 0.2364 &&  -0.3946&&    1.0000
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$   
U =
\begin{bmatrix}
8.0000  && -3.0000 &&   2.0000  && -1.0000\\
             0   && 6.8750  &&  0.7500   && 1.6250\\
             0    &&     0   && 7.4182 &&  -2.9273\\
             0    &&     0    &&     0  &&  6.3358
\end{bmatrix}$$

The question asks to solve *A*

$A = L_2 \times U_2$, where $L_2$ is lower triangular and $U_2$ is unit upper triangular.

So isn't it just $U' \times L'$ to get the answer? Or do I have to use the Cholesky factorization to get the answer?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is asking but according to the Doolittle's method A=L*U. You have found both L2 and U2.

this might also help: http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/CholeskyMod.html